# Ajax Submit problem

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have this code that works ok when search button is pressed, but if one hits the enter button, it does not return any value from the database.

```
function showDetails(str){
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("searchDiv").innerHTML="";
        return;
      }

      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
      else {
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){

  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("searchDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_details.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

Here's how I'm using it in a separate page.

`searchField` is a text input field in my form.

```
<button type="button" name="search" onclick="showDetails(searchField.value)">Search</button>
```

Like I said, it returns data from the server only when the search button is pressed but not when you hit the enter button on the computer keyboard. Is there any way I can make it respond to both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you haven't bound any event to the pressing of a key. Your event is very clearly labeled `onclick`. So it responds to a click. Bind it to a keypress, check if that keypress is the enter key, and if so trigger the ajax request.

Comment: Or better yet, just add it to the form's `onsubmit` event

Comment: @sdleihssirhc - I don't have my computer here, do you mean add on submit and onclick; or just onsubmit?

Comment: @maxedison - Thanks for the tip, will try that.But is there one single event handler that covers both keypress, onsubmit and onclick? or do I need to individually call all these handler in my code when an event is fired. Thanks again for your assistance.

Comment: As far as I can tell, just using `onsubmit` should be sufficient.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc -- he's using AJAX, not a standard <form> element. That makes each of your comments irrelevant (no offense intended). This is precisely why he's attaching the event handler to onclick, not onsubmit. And it is precisely why a binding to the keypress event needs to be done as well. Helen -- following from what I just said, no, there is not a single event handler that will do both. Instead, store the code you want run upon click/enter in a function, and call it in the click & keydown event.

Comment: @maxedison Even if you are just using AJAX, wouldn't using a standard `<form>` element be best?